# TSQL to find if logins have password same as loginname?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I want to check if SQL logins have passwords same as thier login name. E.g. login name 'abc123' has password= 'abc123'.
I need to do this for a security audit across many 2000 and 2005 servers.

Is it possible to check using TSQL?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
select * from syslogins where pwdcompare (name,password)=1
```

BOL: [pwdcompare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822792.aspx)

Comment: And it works on both SQL 2000 and 2005.
thanks for sparing your time.

Comment: Tested in SQL from 2008 to 2014, various editions (dev/stnd/ent). Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Below worked in SQL 2019:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE PWDCOMPARE(name, password_hash) = 1
```